# 2 year old keeps pulling up the couch cushions and laying underneath them - is this a problem?

Tags: toddler, behavior, safety

My 2 year old has a new favorite habit - lifting up the couch cushions and putting himself underneath them.

My wife and I are pretty cautious, and it's not very subtle that he's under there, so he's not in danger of being sat on - but he could be trying to eat food out from the nook of the couch.

Is this a dangerous thing for him to be doing? And, how can we prevent him from doing it?  Pulling him out from it repeatedly doesn't seem to deter him, and encouraging him to sit on the couch or go somewhere else hasn't helped much either.

Comment: I used to do this when I was two or three.  Just keep it clean underneath the cushions and let him have a good time.

Comment: Not a problem, just a phase. If you ignore him, he might stop sooner (he may be doing it for your reaction), but it may just be overall fun for him to "disappear" for a bit. (More fun if you play along. "Where did our boy go?") Both of my granddaughters did this at that age. Not an answer because it would involve a frame challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Kids are drawn to cozy/private spaces, and this is really normal behavior.

But I can hear your concern that there's not much air under there.  I would probably be anxious as well if my kids did that!

Your best bet would be redirection - if you can find him a similar spot with just a *little* more breathing space, and see if it catches on.

- If the cushions are detachable, you can try building him a fort with them
- You can buy a pop-up kids tent
- Or  make a tent with a blanket draped over some furniture.
- If it's in your budget, this fort-couch for kids is adorable https://shorturl.at/lqTWX

Good luck!